# Go back to home screen after Activity finishes

Tags: android, android-activity, homescreen

I have an Activity which keeps beeping till the time the user clicks a button. 
On clicking the button, it displays a message. After displaying the message, instead of the user pressing on the back button to exit, I want my activity to exit to the home screen on its own.

Does the `finish()` method do this? If yes, how and where should I implement it?

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    Intent i= new Intent("package.homescreenactivity");//homescreen of your app.
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
```

Go back to home screen by clearing activity stack.

To understand the whole concept i suggest you take a look at this site. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html.
The site talks about how activity back stack works.

**Update:** (August 15th 2014)

Clearing Backstack may not be a good idea. Please have a look at Effective Navigation design guidelines.

Back button is supposed to take you back to the previous activity.

Check

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear. I meant the default home screen of the android phone. Does this go back to it?

Comment: Cool. The link at the last explains in detail. Read it.

Answer (score 1):

Apply finish() method in all the activity. It will go back to home screen after activity finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1:For Button Click

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Show message here
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
```

case 2:If You want to ask user to go to home

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertbox.setTitle(res.getString("Title"));
            alertbox.setMessage(res.getString("Exit"));
            alertbox.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
            alertbox.setPositiveButton(res.getString(R.string.Yes),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            exit();
                        }
                    });

            alertbox.setNeutralButton(res.getString(R.string.No),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        }
                    });

            alertbox.show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private void exit() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are showing the message as an `alertdialog`, call `finish()` on the button press of the `alertdialog`.

If you are using `Toast()` call `finish()` on button press after `Toast()` is shown.

Answer (score 0):

you can apply `finish()` method at Button `onClick()` and after `startActivity()` call you can apply finish method as shown below.

```
startActivity(intent obj);
finish();
```